# LWC Build Files Explaination

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-oss

I have been trying to research this on my own, but I can't find a simple explanation that tells me the difference between the following 2 files:

`lwc.config.json`https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/09/lightning-web-components-module-resolution.html

`lwc-services.config.js`https://github.com/muenzpraeger/create-lwc-app/blob/main/packages/lwc-services/example/lwc-services.config.js

Are they both necessary or is it a "one or the other" thing we creating an LWC OSS app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**lwc.config.json**

This is needed if you need [module resolution](https://rfcs.lwc.dev/rfcs/lwc/0020-module-resolution) in your LWC OSS project. LWC OSS provides a native modulation resolution for indicating app entry module and bringing third-party npm module and exposing your lwc components as a module.

This is a requirement by [lwc compiler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lwc/compiler).

You will only need the `lwc.config.json` to indicate the entry point for the lwc app. So your project will definitely have one. You can also bring third-party npm or expose your components for distribution using the same file.

This is explained a bit in this quick take [video1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPmY14n7Xe8) and [video2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qn23f-DgBNo)

**lwc-services.config.js**

This is needed if you are using the [create lwc app](https://github.com/muenzpraeger/create-lwc-app) for the creation of lwc. The project is open source and provides `lwc-services` [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lwc-services) for helping you manage other aspects of your JavaScript web application.

> Note it is not mandatory to use this project for scaffolding. You can use rollup or parcel or any other module bundler for managing your web app. However, this project is opinionated with webpack and gives you a head start. It gives you a project with webpack config and an  express server for building client server web app including a PWA app.

The `lwc-services.config.js` is used to indicate app settings documented [here](https://github.com/muenzpraeger/create-lwc-app/blob/main/packages/lwc-services/example/lwc-services.config.js). The file also has the ability to specify webpack custom config.

So both will be needed if you are using the [create lwc app](https://github.com/muenzpraeger/create-lwc-app) for your project else only `lwc.config.json`.

Comment: Thanks @mohith. The reason that I raised this question was around a question of injection / module dependency. When I want to use a certain NPM module (i.e. lightning-base-components / https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightning-base-components), in which file should I be putting the dependency

Comment: lwc.config.json is the file where you will place it!https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/12/build-connected-apps-anywhere-using-lightning-base-components.html

Comment: services is for webpack and express server config